# Local IP being forwarded outside the network

Tags: ip

[image]

In the attached image, the traceroute for 172.16.61.45 shouldnt go to the internet.
Rather it should remain local to my campus LAN shouldnt it?

1.186.15.5 is the IP address of my campus ISP(dvois)
Airtel provides service to dvois

Any idea why the packet is reaching Airtel's network at all?
Shouldnt it remain within the dvois network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that it should remain within the network.  You should contact your NOC (Network Operations Centre) and let them know that private IP space is getting routed out onto the internet so they can fix it for you.

If they are in error, they may also find the following RFC to be of interest:

RFC 3330 - Special-Use IPv4 Addresses
  http://rfc3330.openrfc.org/

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try to make them understand.  They are beyond dumb unfortunately, so I dont really expect much

Comment: @Akash:  Ah, well the RFC should provide some good ammunition for you then.  Please feel free to post an update in a comment here later to let us all know how it turns out.  =)

Comment: My suggestion was met with " We dont support IP addresses" and trying to show them the RFC and tracert results resulted in them accusing me of trying to hack their network.. ( 4 months to go and I'm out of this place)

Comment: @Akash:  They don't support IP addresses?  And referencing an RFC (internet standards documentation) gets you accused of hacking?  Wow!  The word that's often used to describe technical support departments like this is "**clueless**" and, unsurprisingly, probably extends to their approach to security (if they haven't already been hacked, then they are **very lucky**).  They obviously need to be replaced just for their first claim alone that they don't support IP addresses -- _just for fun, you could always ask them if they support IPX addresses._  All I can wish for you is "**good luck!**"  =(

Comment: They change the authentication system every 2-3 months when they get hacked. Currently they are using a portal based login system. All internet login passwords are sent across in plaintext, so someone just needs to run an ARP poisoning attack, and they have a few hundred passwords. Your MAC id uniquely identifies you. Anyone attempting to bring this to anyones attention is accused of "hacking"

Comment: It just keeps getting better with each comment!  Yikes!  What they've set up is a recipe for disaster.  I bet upper management probably don't understand that there are problems here, so a nice anonymous note to them suggesting that they hire a computer security auditor to check the system might actually be good for them -- make sure you include a short list of the major problems about the plain/text passwords being sent over-the-wire and whatnot so that management can show it to the security auditors (to give them a shortcut).  If that doesn't work, then they really are a lost cause.

Comment: We had an "Ethical hacker" visit our campus last year. He brought the network down, and extracted about 1000 userid+password combos in about 10 minutes . ( http://www.hindu.com/2009/09/13/stories/2009091359690600.htm ) Not my college, but same guy